# Forward biasing of EBJ of npn BJT

Tags: education

I apologize for the stupid question, but I am a beginner in the analysis of BJT circuits. The Emitter-Base Junction of a npn BJT is forwand biased if the emitter current is positive?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The B-E junction is forward-biased when the B-E voltage is app. at 0.6...0.7 volts. As a result, an emitter current will come out of the emitter node when - at the same time . the collector is connected to a voltage of at least several volts (emitter grounded).

Answer (score 1):

Under the passive current convention, we say the current is positive when it flows *in* to a pin. So if this convention is followed, when the b-e junction of an NPN BJT is forward biased, the emitter current will be negative.

However, not all engineers consistently use the passive current convention, so you often have to determine from context which direction is meant when a current (or voltage, for that matter) is given, either positive or negative.

Comment: In my case the current flows out of emitter if a I use a npn and flows in emitter if I use a pnp. Thus the EBJ of npn is forward biased when the emitter current is positive.

Comment: 1. "EBJ" is not a common enough acronym to use without explanation. 2. The current flows out of the emitter when the b-e junction is forward biased. Whether you call that "positive" or "negative" is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

When you give forward bias voltage in Base Emitter junction and it's about more them 0.7 V (approximately like diode), and collector emitter voltage around more then 0.2 V (generally used as minimum voltage difference at saturation ); current will flow outwards through the emitter. It's up to you whether you call it positive or negative. Generally when current flow in , it is considered as positive current , but it's just a conventional way.

so strait forward answer of you question is , if there is sufficient current flow through BJT;yeah , your base emitter junction of npn transistor is at forward bias.